# Router requiring reboot - 3 different models

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, freeze

So I have some internet issues that have been happening for a while now (1-2 years) with 3 different router models (PPOE connected through ZTE GPON ONT).

What happens:

- After a while (might be a few days, might be weeks, might be months) the router gets frozen and requires reboot.
- While the router is frozen you cannot access the internet, you cannot even access the LAN admin panel of the router (192.168.0.1).
- Tried 3 different TP-Link models over the years, at some point they all have this issue.
- Latest model is AX3000 AX50 bought on Friday (8 Jan), frozen today.

Difference between freezes:

- All previous models were behaving exactly the same (first 2)
- AX50 got frozen, just the same, but this time after rebooting I got an error message saying WAN is unplugged. I checked my GPON ONT (provided by ISP for fiber internet) and nothing changed excepting the LAN1 (the only available port) that seemed to flash at a slower pace than before.

Fixes:

- Since the routers are not accessible in any way (be it WI-FI which is down, or cable) the only fix is rebooting.
- For AX50 I also had to unplug the ethernet cable from the ONT and plug it back in.

At first I thought the routers were simply dying of old age, but having this happen for a new router is mind blowing. I'm starting to think there is something else going on here.

I don't have much experience when it comes to networking hardware, but my first idea was that somehow the packets sent to the router would cause it to "freeze up" and require a reboot ?
Either from the ONT or from my PC (but it did happen while the PC was off as well).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot one more thing (AX50 is the only model showing this). The Internet LED was orange when it was frozen (inaccessible via LAN) and the manual says "The router’s WAN port is connected, but the internet service is not available."

Comment: Have you tried connecting the modem/router to a UPS.  I was experiencing slight power outages (less than a second) all other equipment in the house wasn't effected.  However, my modem and router, would go into an error state that was only solved by a reboot.  I solved this issue by replacing the UPS it was connected to (dead battery).

Comment: The router was at some point connected to the UPS, however I strongly believe outage is not the case here. 

In my area an outage either takes out the lights, even if for half a second, or it doesn't and my PC UPS alarm goes off when there's any kind of issue with electricity (be it outage or anything else).

Comment: When it was connected to the UPS did you have these problems?  Just consider the UPS solution since It's obviously not a hardware problem.  I was having the same problem for literally months, so I purchase a UPS, when I went to replace it I realized I already had a UPS and the battery was simply dead.

Comment: Yep, same issue.

EDIT: I did forget to mention that the ISP ONT is about 9 years old so I'm not entirely sure its not faulty, but its hard to diagnose since it takes a while until it freezes.

Comment: You have connected both the GPON ONT and the AX50 to a UPS in less than 30 seconds and verified the problem does not exist?

Comment: No, I mentioned I've tried that in the past, not now. Don't have a free UPS on-hand and I'm trying to narrow down possible solutions before spending money on new things that might not help.

Comment: Also its impossible to verify unless weeks/months pass because, as I said, it might take days, weeks or months until it freezes again. Not an exact science unfortunately...